# How to set textbox text within a table from javascript

Tags: javascript

in my webpage project, i have two textbox and a html button and one big table displaying username, age, sex, city and status. I want to put username in a textbox and status in another then click button to set status from client side based on username. How to do it? Plz help?

Comment: and you have tried ...?

Comment: post what you have tried.It is easy to get the problem for us.

Comment: I could not go further, i know i can set it in jquery $('idtextbox').html(value) but this is to be done with their respctive row (here Username) value when match with its row value. What should i do??

Answer (score 0):

u can use jquery library and access text box by its id

```
$('#idtextbox').val('value here');
```

and here is working example for you https://jsfiddle.net/wnnm09ks/